# Using $\epsilon-\delta$ to show that $\lim \frac{x^2 + 1}{2x^3 - 1}$ as $x \rightarrow 1$ is 2.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

So this looks stupid easy, and i'm pretty sure it is.  But I have been working on it (among other problems) all day and cannot figure out.  My first approach was to use the limit property to break it up into two separate limits and then just show that the equality held, but my tasks failed when I couldn't do the proof for $\frac{1}{2x^3-1}$.  I wasn't really shown any process on how to do this and i'm pretty lost.  I've gathered from some introductory videos on youtube that I want to play with $x$ and $\epsilon$ until I have a expression of $\epsilon$ that I can set my $\delta$ equal to.

To start off, we want to find $0<|x - 1| < \delta$ that implies  $|\frac{x^2 + 1}{2x^3 - 1} - 2| = | \frac{-4x^3 + x^2 + 2}{2x^3 - 1}| < \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon$.  This is just straight from the definition.  But I don't have any clever tricks to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want $0<|x-1|<\delta$

Comment: You're correct, sorry.  Going on little sleep lol.

Answer (score 1):

We must show that $$\left|\frac{x^2 + 1}{2x^3 - 1} - 2\right| = |x-1| \cdot  \left|\frac{4x^2 + 3x + 3}{2x^3 - 1}\right| < \epsilon$$

This expression was derived from the factor theorem and polynomial division. We need an upper bound on $\left|\frac{4x^2 + 3x + 3}{2x^3 - 1}\right|$. Restrict $|x-1| < \frac{1}{10}$. The numerator is bounded above in $(0.9, 1.1)$ by $100$ and the denominator is bounded below by $0.1$. This is not difficult to show rigorously, since the numerator and denominator are monotonically increasing in the interval. Also note that both the numerator and denominator are positive.

Thus we have $$\left|\frac{x^2 + 1}{2x^3 - 1} - 2\right| = |x-1| \cdot  \left|\frac{4x^2 + 3x + 3}{2x^3 - 1}\right| < |x-1| \cdot \left|\frac{100}{0.1}\right|< \epsilon$$

We can thus choose $\delta < \min{(\frac {1}{10}, \frac{\epsilon}{1000})}$

Comment: Apologies, but I don't quite see how the numerator is bound above by 100 and how the denominator is bounded below by 0.1.  Could you explain?

Comment: @badeconomist They aren't globally bound by those numbers, just within the interval. Simply check the graphs of the functions. It's not difficult to prove rigorously either.

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(x)
=\frac{x^2+1}{2x^3-1}
$,
to see what happens as
$x \to 1$,
I apply my saying
"always have limits
that go to zero."

Therefore,
let 
$x = 1+y
$,
so we can let
$y \to 0$.

Then
$f(x)
=\frac{x^2+1}{2x^3-1}
=\frac{(1+y)^2+1}{2(1+y)^3-1}
=\frac{2+2y+y^2}{1+3y+3y^2+y^3}
$,
and now it is quite obvious
that this goes to $2$
as $y \to 0$.